# Facebook and LinkedIn are not display og:image and og:description

Tags: graph, protocols, facebook-opengraph

This is my first post on StackoverFlow. Here's my issue. Im trying to get Linkedin and Facebook to recognize the og:image and og:description but no luck. They both pull the description from my "About me" section instead of the og:description and no Image at all.
The image is 320 by 320.

Here's a link to my page. ( work in progress)

[My Website](http://adrianrivero.com)

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an og:description tag in your head.
add it and then check in FB debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fadrianrivero.com%2F
you'll see there exactly what Facebook 'sees' on your page